# Postgesql function subquery, sum, count, order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am developing a database and I need to create a function which gets users that spend more money than others. I have the following tables

```
create table items (
    item_id varchar(50) not null,
    drug_id int not null,
    company_id int not null,
    
    is_active bool not null default true,
    price numeric not null check (price > 0),
    time_updated timestamp not null default now(),

    primary key (item_id),
    unique (item_id),
    unique (drug_id, company_id),
    
    foreign key (drug_id) references drugs(drug_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (company_id) references pharm_companies(company_id) on delete cascade
);

create table users (
    user_id serial not null,
    
    email varchar(100) not null,
    password varchar(1000) not null,
    
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100),
            
    primary key (user_id),
    unique (user_id),
    unique (email)
);


create table orders (
    order_id varchar(50) not null,
    user_id int null, 

    phone_number varchar(50) not null,  
    address varchar(500) not null,
    
    is_canceled boolean not null default false,
    is_completed boolean not null default false,
    
    time_created timestamp not null default now(),
    time_completed timestamp null check (time_completed > time_created),
    time_canceled timestamp null check (time_canceled > time_created),
    
    primary key (order_id),
    unique (order_id),
    
    constraint check_canceled_time_exists_when_canceled check (is_canceled is true and time_canceled is not null or is_canceled is false and time_canceled is null),
    constraint check_completed_time_exists_when_completed check (is_completed is false and time_completed is null or is_completed is true and time_completed is not null),
    constraint check_can_not_be_completed_and_canceled check (is_completed = is_canceled and is_completed is false or is_completed != is_canceled), 

    foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id) on delete set null
);

create table orders_items (
    order_id varchar(50) not null,
    inventory_id int not null,
    price float not null, 
    quantity int not null check (quantity > 0),

    time_updated timestamp not null default now(),
    
    foreign key (inventory_id) references inventory(inventory_id) on delete restrict,
    foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id) on delete cascade,
    
    unique(order_id, inventory_id)
);
```

I would like to sort them by money that they spend, however nothing that I come up with works. Would really like to get help. PLS note that when counting money spend we need to multiply price in orders_items on the quantity, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select o.User_id, sum(oi.price*oi.quantity) as Spend
From.orders o inner join orders_items oi on o.order_id=oi.order_id
Where not o.is_cancelled
Group by User_id
Order by 2 desc
```